# Can I reuse a Windows 7 key on a new computer if I format the old computer?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-10, motherboard

1) Recently I've decided to replace multiple components in my computer because my hard drive is failing and my motherboard and such need an upgrade. Since the pc was built for me, I have a retail version of Windows 7. Is there any way to deactivate Windows 7 on my old computer and use the same disk and license key on the new computer I plan on building? Or will I just get "Windows errors"?

2) I'm assuming if I format my old computer I should be able to reuse the product key, correct? How does one go about formatting the computer?

3) My copy of Windows 7 is for a 32-bit processor, will it work if I get a 64-bit cpu and then upgrade to Windows 10 (the 64-bit version)? (I used the Windows Media Creation tool to dl Windows 10 to a flash drive so I'll have the upgrade even after July 29th)

Sorry for so many questions, all the forums I've looked at have confused me even more

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This has been answered many times here.

Answer (score -1):

1 & 2) You don't need to deactivate the old computer.

For formatting the hard drive, you might want to securely wipe it to prevent anyone from being able to recover files off it. You can boot [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) and select "Darik's Boot and Nuke (DBAN)" to take care of that.

3) You can install Windows 7 (x64). Then enter the product key, and it will probably ask you to do phone activation. It's 100% automated and very simple you just have to do what it says. Once you have Windows 7 activated, then you should be able to upgrade to Windows 10.

**Free Windows 10 upgrades end on July 29th** regardless of if you have Windows 10 downloaded.

Comment: @Ramhound sharktato specifically said " I have a retail version of Windows 7" in the question.